# Integral calculation using Cauchy's theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

I encounter the following problem.

[image: problem]

I solved the problem using Cauchy's theorem. My approach was -

- the point $z=0$ is a singular point [image: reasoning]
- the circle $C$ does not contain the singular point with/within its boundary. so the function is analytic within this domain [image: reasoning]
- so Cauchy's theorem is applicable and integral is 0.

Am I correct?
Is Cauchy's theorem applicable here in this case?

Comment: Please don't use images as essential part of your post. [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Cauchy's theorem or integral formula only apply to functions which are holomorphic or differentiable. $\bar{z}^2$ is not differentiable anywhere on $\mathbb{C}$. (When you are taught complex differentiation, some of the 'standard' examples of non-differentiable functions are $|z|$ and $\bar{z}$ etc. Go check your notes.)

Comment: So I could use Cauchy-Reimann equation to test if it's differentiable everywhere on $C$?

Comment: Yes, or use the definition of complex differentiation.

Comment: @panic: **Riemann** please!! (Why is this misspelled as “Reimann” at least once a day?)